# Pygame Drawing Elements Sequentially to the Screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am making an application that demonstrates sorting algorithms in pygame. I have "Elements" that need to be drawn on the screen 1 by 1 so the user can see what is going on. I have tried doing this, but what happens is that all the elements get drawn on the screen at the same time. This all happens in initialize_elements(). What is supposed to happen is that a new element is created, is then drawn to the screen, and then the display is updated so the user can see the individual element created 1 by 1. Instead, all the elements appear on the screen at the same time. I have tried using pygame.time.delay(100) but that didn't work. I don't know how to stop this from happening.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import random

class Element:

    def __init__(self, left_in, width_in, screen_height, screen):
        self.top = 0
        self.left = left_in
        self.height = random.randrange(screen_height / 4, screen_height * 0.75)
        self.color = (0,0,255)
        self.border = 5
        self.surface = pygame.Surface([width_in, self.height])
        self.surface.fill((self.color))
        self.draw(screen, self.color, left_in, 0)

    def draw(self, screen, color, x, y):
        screen.blit(self.surface, (self.left, self.top))


screen_width = 1400
screen_height = 900
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

num_elements = 20 # Will be determined at start screen

def main():
    pygame.init()
    
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 30
    
    elements = []
    
    pygame.display.set_caption("Sorting Visualization")

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    def initialize_elements(desired_width):
        i = 0
        while i < num_elements:
            if i == 0:
                elements.append(Element(screen_width / 5, desired_width, screen_height, screen))
            else:
                elements.append(Element(elements[i - 1].left + desired_width, desired_width, 
                                        screen_height, screen))
            i += 1
            pygame.display.update()

    # Initializing Elements
    desired_width = (screen_width - (2/5)*screen_width) / num_elements
    initialize_elements(desired_width)
    
    while(True):
        clock.tick(FPS)
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        pygame.display.update()
            
        
main()
```

Comment: Have you considered creating a list of `Element`s before the main loop starts, then just calling Element.draw() at the correct time?  I think part of your problem is the Element class wants to draw directly to the screen as part of `Element.__init__()`

Answer (score 3):

You need to handles the events by [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump), before the update of the display becomes visible in the window.

See [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

If you want to display the lines and delay the game, then you've to update the display and handle the events.

```py
while i < num_elements:
    if i == 0:
        elements.append(Element(screen_width / 5, desired_width, screen_height, screen))
    else:
        elements.append(Element(elements[i - 1].left + desired_width, desired_width, 
                                        screen_height, screen))
    i += 1

    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.delay(delay * 100) # 100 milliseconds = 0.1 second
    pygame.event.pump()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `sleep` in the loop that draws the lines.

Try this code:

```
def initialize_elements(desired_width):
    i = 0
    while i < num_elements:
        if i == 0:
            elements.append(Element(screen_width / 5, desired_width, screen_height, screen))
        else:
            elements.append(Element(elements[i - 1].left + desired_width, desired_width, 
                                    screen_height, screen))
        i += 1
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(.2)   # add this line
```

Comment: This code won't work without event handling

Comment: No that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have re-written your code in a more convenient way with comments which you did not include in yours. And I have separated the code into files, so that it is easier to follow.

The code is broken down into 3 files:

1. main.py - where the animation loop is found,
2. element.py - where the Element class is found.
3. generateInitialElements.py - where the function to generate a list that stores the Elements objects.

This is the Element class:

```
# Import modules
import pygame
# ---------------- #

class Element:
     # Constructor function
     def __init__(self, top_left_coords, dim, color):
          # Initialize global vairables
          self.dim             = dim
          self.color           = color
          self.top_left_coords = top_left_coords

          # Initialize the rect surface representing the element
          self.rect = pygame.Rect(top_left_coords[0], \
                                  top_left_coords[1], dim[0], dim[1])

     def show(self, window):
          # Display the element
          pygame.draw.rect(surface=window, color=self.color, rect=self.rect)
```

This is the generateInitialElements function:

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np
# -------------- #

def generate_initial_elements(num_elements, Element, color, width_element, min_height, max_height, surface_width):
     # List that stores each element
     elements = []

     # Generate a list of random heights
     heights = np.random.choice(np.arange(min_height, max_height+50,50), \
                                size=num_elements) # 50 is an arbirary number

     
     # Calculate the total width of the elements
     total_width = width_element * num_elements

     # The '-' represent empty space 
     # En represent an element where n is its index in the list elements

     # ------------------------- E0 E1 E2 ------------------------------
     # |-----------------------|
     # We need to calculate this length
     # This length is equal to this one   |----------------------------|
     # 
     # So the length will be = (surface_wiidth - total_width) / 2
     # This will be the x coord of the first element, E0
     x = 0.5 * (surface_width - total_width)

     # Generate the x coord of the top_left_coords of each element
     xs = np.linspace(x, x+total_width, num_elements, endpoint=True)

     # Generate the initial element
     for i in range(num_elements):
          elements.append(Element(top_left_coords=[xs[i], 0], dim=[width_element,heights[i]], color=color))

     return elements
```

This is the main code:

```
# Import modules
import pygame
import time
import numpy  as np 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# Import classes
from element import Element

# Import function
from generateInitialElements import generate_initial_elements
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# Initialize all of the
# imported Pygame modules
pygame.init()

# Width and height of window
width  = 1400
height = 900

# Create a window surface of size (width x height)
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# Initialize a clock to 
# set Frames Per Seconds (FPS)
timer_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
     
# FPS
FPS = 50

# Boolean that keeps track if the 
# user has pressed the exit button
running = True

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# Number of elements
num_elements = 20

# Width of each element
width_element = 50.0

# Minimum and maximum height of the elements
# Each element will have a random height between this range
min_height = 50.0
max_height = 600

# Generate the initial elements
elements = generate_initial_elements(num_elements=num_elements, Element=Element, color="blue", \
                                     width_element=width_element, min_height=min_height, max_height=max_height, surface_width=width)

# Index of elements to be displayed for animation
index = 0
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# Animation loop
while running:

     # Set background color for window
     window.fill((30,30,30))

     # Display the elements
     for i in range(index+1):
          elements[i].show(window)

     # Check if all elements has been displayed
     if (index+1 != num_elements):
          index += 1
          time.sleep(0.5) # pause for animation effect


     # PERFORM THE SORT ALGOITHM HERE

     # Iterate through the list of Event 
     # objects returned by pygame.event.get()
     for event in pygame.event.get():
          # Check if the user wants to quit the window
          if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
               # Update running
               running = False
     
     # Update the display
     pygame.display.update()

     # Set FPS
     timer_clock.tick(FPS)

# Quit Pygame after 
# closing the window
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Can you explain how that refactoring addresses the problem of displaying sequentially instead of all at once?

Comment: If you run the code, you will see that it displays sequentially...